# jquery + read multiple img src

Tags: jquery

I have around 8 img src tags that start like this:

```
<img src="" id="joinCityResponse" class="joinResponse"/>
```

If a related question is answered correctly then jQuery adds in the src field.
`src="http://www.staticimages.co/dating/online-dating-index/join_tick.png"`

At the end of the 8 questions I have a Join Now button and I need to be able to know if all the questions have been answered correctly. eg: have the above src url set.

How can I use jQuery to check all img tags with the class 'joinResponse' have the scr as set above?

Comment: What are you talking about? jQuery does not add that.  Also, jQuery is not an acronym.

Comment: hm... wouldn't it be easier and better to just keep track of how many are correct with a variable or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
var allAnswered = $('img.joinResponse').filter('[src="url"]').length == 8;
```

This will get all images with `joinResponse` class and then return only those that have the `src` attribute set to `url` value (replace `url` with your png url).

I would recommend you insteadto just set another class that will mark correctly answered answers.  Then you can just check the number of elements with this class. The advantages are:

1. Checking if all answers are correct is faster (the selector is faster).
2. You won't have the URL hardcoded in multiple places so the code is easier to modify. If you have single variable containing this URL and you are using it everywhere, then ignore this :).

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli You are right - using `filter()` instead. Thanks!

Comment: so used in using filter with a function parameter for complex checks  that i forgot it actually accepts selectors as parameter.. *updating my own as well..*

Comment: thankyou so very much... was trying has() but changed to filter().... so much appreciate it... !!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
var responses = $('.joinResponse');
if (responses.length === responses.filter('[src$="join_tick.png"]').length)){
  // all are correct
}
```

This will check if all the `.joinResponse` elements have an `src` that ends with
 ***join_tick.png***

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
var allSet = true;
$('img.joinResponse').each(function() {
    if(!$(this).attr('src')) {
        allSet = false;
    }
});
// allSet now contains whether all images with the class "joinResponse" have an src attribute that is set to a non-empty string
```

Not the most efficient since it doesn't stop as soon as it finds one such no-src image tag, but if there's only 8 image tags, this should be enough.